# MySQL query to search string in Master-Child tables and return all rows with Master-Child relation

Tags: mysql

Need MySQL query Help.

Please find schema below:

```
Table1
PK_id    Table1_Title    Table1_Description
1        Test1           This is Test1
2        Test2           This is Test2

Table2
FK_id    Table2_Title    Table2_Description
1        Test2           This is Test2  
1        Test3           This is Test3
```

Here "Table2" is in child relationship with Master table "Table1". I want to search in Title and Description columns of above 2 tables. If search string is found in master table "Table1" then that row along with all the rows of child should be returned. Simillarly if search string is found in one of the child tabel row then the coresponding Master table row and all its child should be returned. To clarify please find result below:

Result:

```
Case 1:
If searching TEST2 Then

PK_id    Table1_Title    Table1_Description    FK_id    Table2_Title    Table2_Description
1        Test1           This is Test1         1        Test2           This is Test2
1        Test1           This is Test1         1        Test3           This is Test3
2        Test2           This is Test2         NULL     NULL            NULL


Case 2:
If searching TEST1 Then

PK_id    Table1_Title    Table1_Description    FK_id    Table2_Title    Table2_Description
1        Test1           This is Test1         1        Test2           This is Test2
1        Test1           This is Test1         1        Test3           This is Test3


Case 3:
If searching TEST3 Then

PK_id    Table1_Title    Table1_Description    FK_id    Table2_Title    Table2_Description
1        Test1           This is Test1         1        Test2           This is Test2
1        Test1           This is Test1         1        Test3           This is Test3
```

Is it possible to have a result with single query or something else?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below SQL:

**Updated SQL**

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON  Table1.PK_id = Table2.Fk_id
WHERE CONCAT(Table1_Title, ' ', Table1_Description) LIKE 'test2%'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON  Table1.PK_id = Table2.Fk_id
WHERE Table1.PK_Id IN 
(
    SELECT Table2.Fk_id
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE CONCAT(Table2_Title, ' ', Table2_Description) LIKE 'test2%'
)
```

See **[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67168/10)**

**Another Variant SQL**

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON  Table1.PK_id = Table2.Fk_id
WHERE Table1_Title LIKE 'test3%'
OR Table1_Description LIKE 'test3%'
OR Table1.PK_Id IN 
(
    SELECT Table2.Fk_id
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE CONCAT(Table2_Title, ' ', Table2_Description) LIKE 'test3%'
)
```

See **[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67168/17)**

Where Test2 is the string you need to search.

Comment: Thanks Minesh. But its not as per result expected in case1. It should return 3 rows.

Comment: Thanks Minesh for update. It worked and simple to understand. Thanks again.